# Google chrome extension: local storage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome, and have run into some trouble.I created an options.html page and added it to the manifest.json file.The page shows properly.

I saved the options, and then went back to the page on which the extension is supposed to run.

Unfortunately, the Local storage for the options was returning a 'null' instead of the option. If I set the local storage option directly from the extension's JS script, it works fine but not if it was set from the options page.

Any idea how i can access the options.html local storage values from my Javascript file in the extension?

Comment: So how did you fix it? I'm having the same problem. `options.html` uses localStorage, but the content script knows only the website's localStorage and `background.js`'s localStorage is empty...

Comment: I've fixed it using the new storage API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: At this point, you should be using [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), not [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in Chrome extensions, unless it is specifically your intent to interact with the `localStorage` for a specific website using a content script.

Answer (score 25):

You can set them using either

```
localStorage["var"]=data;
```

or

```
localStorage.var=data;
```

Load them using

```
var myvar = localStorage.var;
```

You can read about the API [here](https://julip.co/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-2-options-and-localstorage/).

Comment: really? it always works for me, maybe it was just temporary?
but at least it works now.

Comment: hi rohan i am facing the same issue can you please post the solution?

Answer (score 13):

The correct method is:

```
if (typeof(localStorage) == ‘undefined’ ) {
  alert(‘Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.’);
}
else {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem(“name”, “Hello World!”); //saves to the database, “key”, “value”
  }
  catch (e) {
    if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
      alert(‘Quota exceeded!’); //data wasn’t successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
    }
  }
  document.write(localStorage.getItem(“name”)); //Hello World!
  localStorage.removeItem(“name”); //deletes the matching item from the database
}
```

REFERENCE: http://html5tutorial.net/tutorials/working-with-html5-localstorage.html

Comment: Yes, this is the robust way to access localStorage for javascripts, but any version of Chrome that supports extensions will support localStorage, so it is redundant.