# Can I access local storage of a specific web with a chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have created a web with jwt files in local storage. And I want to make an extension that automatically logs in to the admin page by importing the jwt file through the chrome extension.
Is it possible to access the local storage of the web with a chrome extension and get information?

Comment: Yes, your content script can access it, then send a message.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand well, what means sending a message?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: if the website, not a content script, store it in the local storage, you can not access it: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988612/do-popup-html-and-background-html-share-the-same-local-storage