# variable scope in chrome extension especially between background page and content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scope

*The question is variable scope in chrome extension.
But i also want information for scope between background page and content scripts*

---

I have a background html and a content script

I have declared a global variable in the start of background page say for example seltext

The content script is listening for mouse up events and in that code i want to update seltext

If this is not possible then i am planning to send seltext value from content script to background page by using sendresponse or i can use local storage. I hope the later will be taking more resources.

Since i am not having an clear picture of chrome extension working completely i am having this doubt.

Any type of response could be helpful.

A partial of what i wanted can be found here

[how to comunicate between a content script and a background page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126984/how-to-comunicate-between-a-content-script-and-a-background-page)

yet detailed information reference about variable scope in chrome extension would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Context isn't shared between the background page and content script. sendRequest is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `setter` and a `getter` for `seltext` in background page and use [chrome-rpc](https://github.com/floydsoft/chrome-rpc) in content scripts to call `seltext`'s `setter` and `getter` for accessing `seltext`.