# clientside filestorage can not read file from content_scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webkit

The problem here is that the things that I'm writing in `popup.js` with `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` can be read from there, but I can not be read from `content.js`.

PS: the code is the same in both files

manifest.json

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "action.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
  ]
}
```

action.html

```
// Here is the popup.js file included
```

popup.js

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, readFromFileStorage, errorHandler);

function readFromFileStorage(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile('file.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          console.log(this.result);
        };

       reader.readAsText(file);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}
```

content.js

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, readFromFileStorage, errorHandler);
// the function 'readFromFileStorage' is the same as in "popup.js"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System/Introduction?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FAPI%2FFile+System%2FIntroduction#origin)**:

> The security boundary imposed on file system prevents applications from accessing data with a different origin.

`popup.js` and a content script injected into a webpage are considered two different origins, so you cannot access the data stored in one's filesystem from the other.
Based on your requirements and particula setup, **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)** you could use message passing to communicate and pass data between a content script and the popup or background page.

Comment: thanks, didn't knew that
PS. This answer here about `message passing` was easier for me to understand than the official google documentation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937000/chrome-extension-accessing-localstorage-in-content-script