# How to read configuration set in option page from content_scripts of Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using localStorage, I try to store users configs, and it works well.

```
// in options_page
localStorage.setItem('myKey',someVal);
```

But it's difficult to read this configs from content_scripts (´･ω･`)

```
localStorage.getItem('myKey');
// because different 'window' scope
```

I'm making it by using runtime.sendMessage

```
// in content_scripts
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, {purpose:'getConfig',configKey:'myKey'},
    function(confHere){
        // some action
    }
);
```

I think it's complex!! (and using 'chrome.storage' requires permission, ugly)
Is there any way to read configs from content_scripts of Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content scripts run within the context of the pages that they are sharing the DOM with and not the extension. So, a content script trying to read from `localStorage` will read from the `localStorage` of the page, and not the extension.

The way you proposed is correct and as far as I know the best way to access setting info in your content script. So, when the content script is created send a message to the background to get the settings (as you have done) and then in background add a listener that will return those settings. It's not super clean ... but it is intuitive when you think of what content scripts are supposed to be (and not be).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937000/chrome-extension-accessing-localstorage-in-content-script) is a SO answer that outlines exactly what you need (although from the sounds of it you already know what must be done :)) Also, if you are interested the [content script page of the extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) has some good (and short) videos at the bottom that helped me understand the ideas behind what content scripts should be able to do.