# localStorage different for webpage and chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to access the `localStorage` object from my chrome extension's `background.js` file. The `localStorage` object on a regular webpage shows me items from different webpages (including the ones I'm interested in), but the ones I access from `background.js` or `popup.js` are empty. How do I access the regular `localStorage` (with items set by another webpage) from my Chrome extension?

Comment: Kind of inverse of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937000/chrome-extension-accessing-localstorage-in-content-script

Answer (score 3):

The `localStorage` object is relative to the "local environment", this means that the `localStorage` object on `http://www.google.com` is ***totally different*** from the one on `http://stackoverflow.com`, and obviously is totally different from the one in the background page of your extension.

Given that, if you want to store something in your extension, you'll need to use the `localStorage` object **in your background page**, not in the page of some site you are injecting content scripts to.

If you want to access web pages' `localStorage`s, then you'll have to send a content script on it, retrieve the `localStorage` object, and send it to the `background.js` script with a message (see [chrome extensions message passing](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.chrome.com%2Fextensions%2Fmessaging&ei=PixAVNfPJcL8aOSSgdgH&usg=AFQjCNGcNDYu-yaqEnY2oL3b-P0xwtShdg&sig2=5we8-rEAMq7r-0DxAAXm1w&bvm=bv.77648437,d.d2s)).

Documentation on `localStorage` from MDN: **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)**.

Comment: Pages store some interesting data in their `localStorage` sometimes. So that's the point.

Comment: Emphasis on the fact that `localStorage` is part of DOM, and as such is only accessible from content scripts of open tabs.