# How to get Chrome Extension's Options value in Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am learning Chrome Extension and created a sample Options page in it and storing a input's value in localStorage using the code in **options.js**

```
localStorage['refresh_rate'] = document.getElementById('refresh_rate').value;
```

And this is working on the options.html page, it is receiving the value inside localstorage, but when I am trying to get the same in extension, it is giving value undefined.

I wrote:

```
alert(localStorage['refresh_rate']);
```

and it is alerting a text - **undefined**
Is there any other method to get the value?

Please note: i have already allowed storage in manifest.json using below lines

```
"permissions": [
    "storage"
]
```

Comment: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937000/chrome-extension-accessing-localstorage-in-content-script)

Comment: `localStorage` != `chrome.storage`