# how to use key that is stored in localstorage of addon/extension in firefox/chrome browser for web apps

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-app

My question might be bit consfusing but ill try to explain as simple as i can

lets say my Addon is having a particular key value pair

where i can use that key and its value in my addon/chrome itself no doubt about it

but is there any way where i can get  the localstorage key value pairs of my addon and use them in my

browser

in simpler terms if i have a key/value pair in addon and i want to use the same key value pair in my angular application

lets say

`localstorage.getitem('key')`

in my angular application should yield the value of that particular key stored in my addon

Comment: Switch to chrome.storage.local which you can use in the content script directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension: accessing localStorage in content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937000/chrome-extension-accessing-localstorage-in-content-script)