# It is possible to login the user into chrome extension using the local storage of our website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I am trying to build my first browser extension, In this extension I want users to automatically login if the access key of our website is present in local storage.
It is possible to build functionality like that if yes then how?

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937000/chrome-extension-accessing-localstorage-in-content-script

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the link you shared is about the local storage of extension & I am asking for the local storage of my website

Answer (score 0):

Local storage has a different purpose. For login you should use cookies.
Why? Cookies are mainly for reading server-side, whereas local storage can only be read by the client-side. Apart from saving data, a big technical difference is the size of data you can store, and as I mentioned earlier, localStorage gives you more to work with.

In conclusion, you cannot use local storage because for login you need a server side readable storage.