# Store informations locally?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google chrome extension: local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033829/google-chrome-extension-local-storage)

How can I store informations locally for my Chrome Extensions..

I have tried using [localStorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage), and I have aswell tried to make a txt document, where my javascript should write the informations.

But all without luck.

Hope someone can help me figure out how I can save informations locally for my Chrome Extensions.

And also how I can access the informations and check if a special information is set?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Show us what exactly you've tried.

Comment: Yea saying "I've tried this thing that should work but it didn't work" without showing us how you tried isn't going to get us very far.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanteisnotaGeek, I have got it fixed now. I used the localStorage the wrong way.